# javascript add tag before and after another

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```
<div id="pageNavigator" class="rbcContentBlock">
<ul>
<a href="/home/">Úvod</a>
<span><span> &gt; </span></span>
<a href="/fontanova-cerpadla/">Fontánová čerpadla</a>
<span><span> &gt; </span></span>
<span id="navCurrentPage">Pontec PondoVario 1000</span>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like to put "li" tags before and after tags "a". I tried to make something, here is my javascript code:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("pageNavigator");
var elements = div1.getElementsByTagName("a");
var parentDiv = elements.parentNode;
var li = document.createElement("li");
parentDiv.insertBefore(li, elements);
```

What's wrong with this code? Is the problem that elements is "array"? Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't manipulate tags in Javascript. You manipulate DOM nodes.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko jQuery isn't needed.

Comment: And yeah, a collection of nodes doesn't have a single parentNode.

Comment: @JanDvorak, jQuery is never needed. Everything you can do in jQuery can be don't with pure javascript, it just makes it easier to use jQuery.

Comment: The truth is, the nice thing about jQuery is that it lets you manipulate _collections_ of nodes. So, if you do rewrite this code, consider using jQuery so that you don't have to loop manually.

Comment: Are you trying to change `<a href="/home/">Úvod</a>` into `<li></li><a href="/home/">Úvod</a>` or into `<li><a href="/home/">Úvod</a></li>` ?

Comment: <li><a href ...>anchor</a></li> :-)

Comment: @user2129659 then you need to _wrap_ the original element. That is, place the old element into the new element and the new element into the old element's original position. jQuery does that quite well ;-)

Comment: `$("#pageNavigator a").wrap("<li>")`. Poof, you're done.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I though jQuery wasn't needed?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko it's not, but it's easier with :-)

Comment: The code you have is invalid to begin with. Where are you getting it from? Can't you fix it at the root?

Comment: @JanDvorak i've inserted this into <script></script>: $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#pageNavigator a').wrap('<li>');
            });
but it doesn´t do anything. jquery library included of course :-)

Comment: $("#pageNavigator a").wrap("<li>") from @JanDvorak works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should wrap each anchors in a list item tag.

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("pageNavigator");
var ul = div1.children()[0];
var elements = div1.getElementsByTagName('a');

var(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.replaceChild(li, element);
    li.appendChild(element);
}
```